# virtualenvwrapper side-by-side with python2.7 and python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm starting to do side-by-side work in python2 and python3. (i.e. some projects req python 2 and some req python 3)

How do i use virtualenvwrapper with this requirement?

Do I just install one virtualenvwrapper (either for 2 or for 3) and just set the python binary accordingly at time of virtual env creation? Doesn't seem like that would work.

Comment: Have you actually tried creating two virtualenvs? Or are you asking without having tried anything? :)

Comment: still in the process of setting up the python3 project right now. so can't test yet =P. while waiting thought i would ask

Answer (score 1):

Just doing some initial testing right now and it looks like it works without issue. I'm running the python 3 version of virtualenv wrapper with the python 3 binary, but am able to create venvs for python2.x just fine

e.g.

```
mkvirtualenv myenv -p /usr/lib/python
```

My existing venvs also working without issue (so far) with this setup

Answer (score 0):

You could just make two separate virtualenvs and specify which python version you'd like on each. Activate them for your python 2 and 3 projects, respectively with:

```
. ~/.VirtualEnv#/bin/activate
```

For example:

`virtualenv -p python2.7 ~/.VirtualEnv2`

`virtualenv -p python2.5 ~/.VirtualEnv3`

Comment: i'm specifically asking about virtualenvwrapper. because the shortcut convenience commands like mkvirtualenv remain the same, i'm wondering how it would work in a 2.x side-by-side with 3.x scenario